# localhost(wamp) form inputs are filled with some 'default' values?

Tags: forms, input, localhost

I am on localhost, I am using wamp server and I`ve made a page index.html which has a form with two inputs for name and password.

```
<form method="POST" action="" >
    User: <input type="text" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This is all the code from my page. The problem is that when I run this page on a browser, these two inputs are autocompleted with an old username that I use it long time ago within another app and with password corresponding with that username probably, which I can't see it because it has `type=password`...

[image]

If I change from `type = password` to `type = text`, or if I delete the `form` tag, these values won`t appear after I refresh the page.

How can I get rid by these 'default' values? I`ve tried to clear all browser data, cookies, files, cache, etc., but no success. Any idea?

Comment: These values are saved in your browser, so the question is not about programming. However, I will not flag or downvote your question, because maybe you thought the values are saved on the server.

Comment: well I think on the server, because as I said, I`ve cleared the cache and all data from the browser history...and the same values are both on chrome and firefox

Comment: Also the saved passwords? These are normally _not_ cleared when you do so to "all" data.

Comment: I've used the command ctrl + shift + delete and on that popup I've checked all those checkboxes, at the period I`ve selected all and hit ok, but nothing

Comment: Extras -> Preferences -> Security -> Saved Passwords

Comment: This data is not coming from the server. It is coming from your browser.

Comment: omg, so dumb :D thanks!